# Remove the first-line block during HTML rendering by marked, a markdown parser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, markdown

I am using marked to parse markdown content. During rendering, I get the first line of every post in blocks. How to get rid of it ?

[image]

**Image : Displays first-line as a block**

I am using [marked cdnjs](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/marked)

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/marked/0.3.6/marked.min.js
```

I am using [jQuery 1.12.4](https://code.jquery.com) (minified)

```
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"   integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I am using `class = "content-markdown"` to allow javascript to find the contents to parse.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".content-markdown").each(function(){
            var raw_content = $(this).text()
            var marked_content = marked(raw_content)
            $(this).html(marked_content)
        })
    })
</script>
```

The content :

```
<div class = "content-markdown">
    <p> {{post.body|safe}} </p> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have **a leading space** in `<p> {{post.body|safe}} </p>`, this creates  `<pre>` in markdown.

Try to remove it: `<p>{{post.body|safe}}</p>`

Comment: This didn't work with the `p tag` alone. But works with `<div class = "content-marked"><p>{{post.body}}</p></div>`. Thanks !

Comment: But why was only the first line shown in block and rest normal?

Comment: @build_code markdown is interpreting doubled line breaks as new paragraphs or other block elements, like in your first line, as `<pre>`. Before 'apples have been...' you have 2 line breaks, but __no__ leading space. So markdown renders a new paragraph.